# Javascript - Two parameters and return object

Tags: javascript

So I have been started kinda basic with JavaScript and trying to learn to programming in JavaScript at this point. I have been studying Java before but I can't really get this on my mind. How to make it to work. Been doing some really weird stuff but no luck haha.

Anways

Im stuck at this sort of:

```
function item(big, low) {
}    
var items = item(5, 10);
console.log(items.big); 
console.log(items.low);
```

so what i'm trying to do is like what you see. I want to print it just for each objects in the console.log. But can't get it to work. I tried to do a `return big; return low;` but no luck. I would more appreciate what I should think rather than have the code written. What should I think at this point?

EDIT:

```
function Triangle(big, low) {
    return { 
        big: big, low: low
        }
}    
var items = item(5, 10);

console.log(items.height);
console.log(items.width);

console.log(items.area());
```

so now I want to use a method and to a math function with area() "height * width" but when I did this:

```
function Triangle(big, low) {
        return { 
            big: big, low: low
            }
    }  
function Area(big, low) {
}  
    var items = item(5, 10);

    console.log(items.height);
    console.log(items.width);

    console.log(items.area());
```

it immediately told me that area() is not a function. What did I go wrong?

Comment: There's one too many closing braces (`}`) in your questions code

Comment: your approach is wrong what you want to achieve can you be more clear?

Comment: from function `item` return an object with two properties: `return {big: big, low: low}`

Comment: do you want to store the value in `items` returned from function `item()`

Comment: Bartek Gladys have posted the right thing. Now im at the point I dont really understood what happened. It worked but why :O?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define what you want return.

```
function item(big, low){  
    return { big: big, low: low}
}
```

Comment: Oh. Could you explain what the big: big and low: low does? what does the ":" do it this case :)?

Comment: The `big:` is your key, later you can get value by this key, like this `something.big`. The second `big` is your argument.

Comment: Oh well! that was a really good thing. Didn't knew there was something like that and also couldn't find it on the book I had. Maybe later on. I just started with this :) Thank you!

Comment: same thing, as before. You didn't declare any `return` in your `Area`.

Comment: I just did this: No luck function area(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    var a = height * width / 2;
    return a;
}

Comment: @Thrillofit123 try this: `function area(height, width) { this.height = height; this.width = width; this.a = this.height * this.width / 2; return a; } `

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: tri.area is not a function

Comment: Ops, console.log(items.area());

Answer (score 0):

```
function item(first, second) {
  var firstIsBigger = first > second
  var big = firstIsBigger ? first : second
  var low = firstIsBigger ? second: first}

  return {big: big, low: low}
}

item(5, 10) //returnes {big: 10, low: 5}
```

ES6 solution:

```
const item = (...numbers) => {
  cosnt [min, max] = numbers.sort()

  return {max, min}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can have `n` number of arguments
- `Math.min` and `Math.max` will determine min and max value from `arguments` array.

```js
function item() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, args);
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, args);
  return {
    big: max,
    low: min
  }
}

var items = item(5, 10);

console.log(items.big);
console.log(items.low);
```

Comment: I haven't came so far yet into programming where I have used slice.call yet. but the code worked fine too. :) Thank you!

Comment: May be I was wrong but i assumed you have many parameters and you are not certain about the order of the parameters...